# Why do thread behave different with different run method body?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, volatile

This code is from Effective Java (Item 66): (without sync or volatile this never ends)

```
public class ThreadPractice {
static boolean canrunstatic;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (!canrunstatic){i++;}
            System.out.println("finished");
        }
    });
    backgroundThread.start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    canrunstatic = true;
}
```

As Bloch mentioned in that chapter it will never write "finished" to the console. I've been playing around with this class, and add that line to the runnable run method:

```
System.out.println("im still running");
```

With this the while loop doesn't only increment i but prints out this string in every loop. But what drives me crazy, that this way the thread stops after 1 sec, when main thread comes back from sleep.

modified: (stops without volatile/sync)

```
public class ThreadPractice {
static boolean canrunstatic;


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (!canrunstatic){i++;System.out.println("im still running");}
            System.out.println("finished");
        }
    });
    backgroundThread.start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    canrunstatic = true;


}
```

So what is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisely, it is just **not guaranteed** that the thread will ever stop, but it is **not forbidden** that it does stop. The logic behind this is provided by the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4), which is a rather complicated topic, but needed in order to understand Multithreading in Java.

The concept is that a write to a non-volatile field of one thread is only required to be seen by another thread if these two actions *synchronize with each other*. A compiler is allow to reorder some actions if the behavior exhibited by the thread it is executed in does not change. But another thread might see this. So you need proper *synchronization* in order to tell the compiler that reordering is not allowed in some parts.

Read the full paper about this here: [JSR-133](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Writing data to the console is often implemented a thread safe operation.

In that case your act of writing data to the console can also trigger updating of the `canrunstatic` variable as seen by your `backgroundThread`.

Note that this is not promised by the Java Memory Model, nor by the implementation of java `System.out`

Comment: That is not specified anywhere in the memory model. Writing to the console is an external operation in the JMM, but this does not guarantee synchronization and dues not create a synchronizes-with edge. So this is not an explanation for the logic behind this.

Comment: Good point, this is the cause, but it is not required that it happens. I've updated the answer to reflect this.